# Prolog predicate that compares values in facts

Tags: prolog

This is my first time using Prolog

I have employees

```
employee(eID,firstname,lastname,month,year)
```

example :

```
employee(1,liz,white,4,2000).
employee(2,ted,johnson,5,1998).
```

I want  to make a predicate `senior(X,Y)` that will return true if the first employee is older in the company.

I have this:

```
senior(X,Y) : -
  employee(X,firstname,lastname,month,year),
  employee(Y,firstname,lastname,month,year),
  X.year < Y.year.
```

but this always return false. I can't understand the reason.

How can I make this predicate work?

Comment: That is no way to run a company, and is illegal in Europe. You must not discriminate by age, except if there is a valid reason (e.g. the law limits working hours for people below a curtain age).

Comment: lol, btw this  is the date that  the employee hired !

Comment: If you mean date employee **was** hired, then it is less dodgy. However I still do not see what value it is to compare people, like this. One person may have been in the company a few weeks, but be much better at a particular job than someone that was there 10 years.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it mandatory that you do this with one rule? You could use one rule for comparing employees who were hired in different years, and a second rule for comparing employees who were hired in the same year. To expand on this, let's say you have employees listed this way:

```
employee(eid,year,month,day)
```

and, of course, a list of employees. You could use the following three rules:

```
% For employees that were hired in different years.
senior(Eid1,Eid2) :-
    employee(Eid1,X,_,_),
    employee(Eid2,Y,_,_),
    X<Y.

% For employees that were hired in the same year, different month.
senior(Eid1,Eid2) :-
    employee(Eid1,Year,X,_);
    employee(Eid2,Year,Y,_);    % Notice how one common variable "Year" is used
    X<Y.

% For employees that were hired in the same year, same month, different day,
% the rule is "expanded" from the previous one.
senior(Eid1,Eid2) :-
    employee(Eid1,Year,Month,X);
    employee(Eid2,Year,Month,Y);
    X<Y.
```

Make sure you don't forget and replace "Year" and/or "Month" with underscores, because then somebody hired on *2010-01-01 (ISO 8601)* would be shown as senior to someone hired on *2005-12-12*.

Then again, perhaps you should catalogue all dates in *ISO 8601:2004*. No matter how big your employee list, you could write a small script to convert

```
employee(eID,firstname,lastname,month,year)
```

to

```
employee(eID,firstname,lastname,yyyymm)
```

Answer (score 1):

In Prolog, variables start with either an underscore or an upper case letter. E.g. `firstname` is an *atom*, i.e. a constant, but `FirstName` is a *variable*. But, in your specific question, you don't care about the employee names. Thus, you can replace those arguments by the *anonymous* variable:

```
senior(X,Y) : -
  employee(X, _, _, Xmonth, Xyear),
  employee(Y, _, _, Ymonth, Yyear),
  ...
```

Can you now complete the code by writing the necessary comparisons  using the `Xmonth`, `Xyear`, `Ymonth`, and `Yyear` variables?